# terraform azure dynamic rule creation based on map

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to get more flexible in my NSG rule creation. I tried to handle the following map:

```
Backend = {
  subnet_postfix = "128.0/17"
  add_nsg        = true
  rules = [
    {
      name                       = "Rule1"
      direction                  = "Outbound"
      access                     = "Allow"
      protocol                   = "Tcp"
      priority                   = 200
      source_port_range          = "*"
      source_port_ranges         = []
      destination_port_range     = ""
      destination_port_ranges    = [5432, 5438, 5450]
      source_address_prefix      = "*"
      destination_address_prefix = "10.2.4.0/22",
    },
    {
      name                       = "Rule2"
      direction                  = "Outbound"
      access                     = "Allow"
      protocol                   = "Tcp"
      priority                   = 300
      source_port_range          = "*"
      source_port_ranges         = []
      destination_port_range     = "80"
      destination_port_ranges    = []
      source_address_prefix      = "*"
      destination_address_prefix = "0.0.0.0/0"
    }
  ]
}
```

The issue I'm running into is in Rule1, where I decided to specify destination_port_ranges instead of only one destination_port_range. It works fine in Rule2 because an empty destination_port_ranges is ok, but I can't figure out what to do in Rule1 when I don't want to specify a range instead a list of ranges. I need to be able to say "no value" for destination_port_range.

The issues I'm running into are that the map has to have the same number of elements, so I can't leave out what I don't want to specify, and I need to be able to handle it in the following dynamic block:

```
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "appnsg" {
  for_each = {
    for k, v in(var.subnet_size == "large" ? var.subnet_map_large : var.subnet_map_small) : k => v
    if contains(var.nsg_enabled, k)
  }
  name                = "${var.client_name}-${each.key}-nsg"
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name

  dynamic "security_rule" {
    for_each = each.value["rules"]
    content {
      name                       = security_rule.value.name
      priority                   = security_rule.value.priority
      direction                  = security_rule.value.direction
      access                     = security_rule.value.access
      protocol                   = security_rule.value.protocol
      source_port_range          = security_rule.value.source_port_ranges == [] ? security_rule.value.source_port_range : ""
      source_port_ranges         = security_rule.value.source_port_ranges
      destination_port_range     = security_rule.value.destination_port_ranges == [] ? security_rule.value.destination_port_range : ""
      destination_port_ranges    = security_rule.value.destination_port_ranges
      source_address_prefix      = security_rule.value.source_address_prefix
      destination_address_prefix = security_rule.value.destination_address_prefix
    }
  }
}
```

In other words, I'm not sure how to test in the dynamic block of the NSG group for the absence of a value or how to better structure this.
I'm looking for something similar to SQL which is also declarative like:

```
  case when 
    security_rule.value.source_port_ranges == [] 
  then 
    source_port_range = security_rule.value.source_port_range
  else
    source_port_ranges = security_rule.value.source_port_ranges
  end
```

Thanks for any idea!

Comment: You haven't explained what's exactly wrong with your current code. Any errors, unexpected behavior? If yes, what exactly is expected one, and the actual one?

Comment: Sorry, you're right. What I don't like with the code is that I'm actually assigning ..port_range and ...port_ranges at the same time with one being an empty string which makes no sense to me. I would love to not assign it at all if there is no value. I tried "null" but that generates an error. At the moment, I'm using it as is.